# Where is the "age threshold" for the referenced object stored in Garbage Collection process stored?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand how GC works and have been reading
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Garbage Collection Process, point #6 says,

"After a minor GC, when aged objects reach a certain age threshold (8 in this example) they are promoted from young generation to old generation."

I am trying to understand where the "age threshold" for the referenced object stored?

Comment: in the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in one of the two headers that any java Object has. The information of how it is stored can be [read from the comments under the source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/oops/markWord.hpp#l33).

You can even track those bits and see how they change, from promotion to promotion, using the awesome `JOL` library. See [this, as an example](https://github.com/openjdk/jol/blob/master/jol-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jol/samples/JOLSample_19_Promotion.java).